# How can I avoid an undesired URL address change after a form submission?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am working on a bootsrap3 template, which is Ajax based.
My index file has a leftside menu and a conent block middle of the page, every time I click on a subelement of this left menu, an Ajax laod will put the page content in this block(ajax-content).*

*Any time I call any page,* **my URL normally looks something like this /index.php#page-one.php**, *except when the page contains form submission*.

**The Problem happens when I add an action attribute (acion="page-one.php") to my form tag. 
After the form submission my URL turns to /page-one.php ;**
consequently I get a white page containing the page-one.php elements whitout any CSS styling and of course no index-file's elements.

What is the correct and best way to come a cross this issue?

index.php:

```
 <body>
    <!--Start Container-->
    <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="sidebar-left" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
                <ul class="nav main-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a id="configuration" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
                            <i class="fa fa-gears"></i>
                            <span class="hidden-xs">Menu-element</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="ajax-link" href="page-one.php">Menu-Subelement-one</a></li>
                            <li><a class="ajax-link" href="page-wo.php">Menu-Subelement-two</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul> <!-- end of main-menu-->
            </div>  
            <!--Start Content-->
            <div id="content" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
                <div class="preloader">
                    <img src="img.gif" class="loader" alt="preloader"/>
                </div>
                <!--inside this div a short description/introduction(simple text inside a <p> tag) about the Menu-element will be shown-->
                <div id="content-header"></div>
                <!--inside this div the page content of the Menu-subelement will be shown-->
                <div id="ajax-content"></div>
            </div>
            <!--End Content-->      
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End Container-->
    <script src="plugins/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugin/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

And here is my script.js:

```
 //
//  Function for load content from url and put in $('.ajax-content') block
//
function LoadAjaxContent(url){
    $('.preloader').show();
    $.ajax({
        mimeType: 'text/html; charset=utf-8', // ! Need set mimeType only when run from local file
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#ajax-content').html(data);
            $('.preloader').hide();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        },
        dataType: "html",
        async: false
    });
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
document.ready
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ajax_url = location.hash.replace(/^#/, '');
    if (ajax_url.length < 1) {
        ajax_url = 'home.php';
    }
    LoadAjaxContent(ajax_url);
    $('.main-menu').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        var parents = $(this).parents('li');
        var li = $(this).closest('li.dropdown');
        var another_items = $('.main-menu li').not(parents);
        another_items.find('a').removeClass('active');
        another_items.find('a').removeClass('active-parent');
        if ($(this).hasClass('dropdown-toggle') || $(this).closest('li').find('ul').length == 0) {
            $(this).addClass('active-parent');
            var current = $(this).next();
            if (current.is(':visible')) {
                li.find("ul.dropdown-menu").slideUp('fast');
                li.find("ul.dropdown-menu a").removeClass('active')
            }
            else {
                another_items.find("ul.dropdown-menu").slideUp('fast');
                current.slideDown('fast');
            }
        }
        else {
            if (li.find('a.dropdown-toggle').hasClass('active-parent')) {
                var pre = $(this).closest('ul.dropdown-menu');
                pre.find("li.dropdown").not($(this).closest('li')).find('ul.dropdown-menu').slideUp('fast');
            }
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('active') == false) {
            $(this).parents("ul.dropdown-menu").find('a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active')
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('ajax-link')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).hasClass('add-full')) {
                $('#content').addClass('full-content');
            }
            else {
                $('#content').removeClass('full-content');
            }
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            window.location.hash = url;
            LoadAjaxContent(url);
        }
        if ($(this).attr('href') == '#') {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
   $('#formSubmit').ajaxForm(); 

});
```

page-one.php:

```
<!--some php code here-->

<form class="validateForm" id="formSubmit" action="page-one.php" method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-8">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-label-left">
                <span><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</span> 
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue to solve for the intranet I work on.
For me, the good way to do this is to avoid using submit method and use instead an input button with a js function to send the form data.

In my case, I did this:

```
<!-- At the top of my webpage -->
<script language='Javascript'>
function loadingAjax(div_id,user,date1,date2)
{
    $("#"+div_id).html('<br><center><img src="images/loading.gif"><br><br><font color="#006699" face="arial" size="4"><b>Loading data<br>VPlease wait ...</b></font></center>');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "activities.php?USER="+user+"&DATE1="+date1+"&DATE2="+date2,
        success: function(msg){
            $("#"+div_id).html(msg);
        }
    });
}
</script>

<!-- And here is my form -->
    <form id='date_form'>
<input type='text' id='user'><input type='text' id='date1'><input type='text' id='date2'>
<input type='button' onclick="loadingAjax('myDiv',document.getElementById('user').value,document.getElementById('date1').value,document.getElementById('date2').value);">
</form>
```

This allow to send your form in a separate DIV without having to show to everyone your URL.

MORE: you can even use this function to manage your left side menu selection so that your URL would stay '/index.php' all the time.

Hope this help

Regards

Nico

Comment: You're welcome Renee, do not hesitate to ask me some more explanations to fit it to your code.

Comment: Did you get throught this Renee?

Comment: I used jquery's `$post()` method inside my click event. Almost the same you've suggested here. Thanks a lot again for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to submit the form, using ajax?

If you want to use ajax, you should cancel the default action like you do with your links using `e.preventDefault();`. Post the javascript that handles the form submit if you need help with that.

If you want to post to `page-one.php` without using ajax, you could add a `header()` redirect after the php code that processes the form to redirect to the page that you would like to show after the form gets submitted.

Comment: Thaks Jeroen, as I commented to Akshay, I'm using jquery-form plugin. Here is the link (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). I'll add the code lines to my script.js and index.php here to make it clear how I call the function.

Comment: Actually I was about to make another question about my ajax submit later. But it seems both problems rely on my failure submitting the form.

Comment: @user4210669 That plugin should automatically make an ajax call instead of doing a regular form submit. Do you have any (error...) messages in the console? By the way, to be safe you'd better use an absolute path for the action like `/page-one.php`. Perhaps the plugin can't find the url.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen for responding me. Well yes I got "undefined is not a function" for my ajaxSubmit call inside the document.ready!

I tried to do some simple alert and also console.log("print something out") when I call ajaxSubmit, but nothing happened.

Comment: I'm pretty new in Ajax and know alitte about php.
There are two things here: 
1.I need definitely "index.php#" in my URL to get nice-looking page.My question is,
whether action attribute accepts "#" for an absolute path at all?
I tried absolute path without "#" but didn't help.

Comment: 2.I looked all around the web to find out, why I get "undefined is not a function"  error. Didn't find my answer yet but got some clue, that the order I call my plugins, may cause this.(I have dozen of plugins)
But don't know which order is the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

As you are loading content by ajax, 
You can post content to page-one.php and redirect user to it's previous page. But it will be  difficult manage and show error, success, notification message like form validation errors etc.
Another and I think best solution is to use ajax form submission

Comment: Well I don't want to reload/redirect the page after I put the content by ajax. And for the Submission, I  already use jquery-form plugin(which does ajax submission). But I get "undefined is not a function" error from the console.

Comment: Are you loading jquery-form plugin on page load or on every ajax call which load page content? And can you show me your ajax form submit code? And may be your ajax form submit is not working becuase of this error which causing to stop further javascript execution. Where is that error comming from? Is that from plugin or from your index page? I think if you sort out "undefined is not a function" problem, then your ajax form submit will also work.

Comment: Thanks Akshay! Yes this is the  case, I am using jquery form plugin here is the link(jquery.malsup.com/form). If you'd like to know more, you might read my comments for Jeroen. I explained everything there. I'm really eager to know how should I load plugins without problem.

Comment: First, your form is loading by ajax, So, you should put your code "$('#formSubmit').ajaxForm();" inside "LoadAjaxContent" function on ajax success event. This will attach ajax submit event to ajax loaded content. And also try jquery noConflict [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/]. And use "jQurey" instead of "$"